# Find one item from a list

Tags: elm

New to Elm..
I am trying to get one item from a list.

This is the model (forgot in the first posting)
I assume that the Report.id has to be an Int !!??

```
-- MODEL


type alias Model =
    { reports : List Report
    , alertMessage : Maybe String
    }


type alias Report =
    { id : Int
    , city : String
    , country : String
    }


initialModel : Model
initialModel =
    { reports = []
    , alertMessage = Nothing
    }


-- UPDATE


type Msg
= NewReports (Result Http.Error (List Report))
  | ShowReport
  | CloseAlert

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
case msg of
    NewReports (Ok weatherReports) ->
        ( { model | reports = weatherReports }, Cmd.none )

    NewReports (Err error) ->
        ( { model | alertMessage = Just (httpErrorToMessage error) }, Cmd.none )

    CloseAlert ->
        ( { model | alertMessage = Nothing }, Cmd.none )

    ShowReport model ->
        ( ??? )

--VIEW now more complete to get the right picture

viewReportRow : Report -> Html Msg
viewReportRow report =
    tr []
        [ td [] [ text report.city ]
        , td [] [ text report.country ]
        , td [] []
            [ button
             [ class "button primary small"
             , onClick (ShowReport report.id)
             ]
             [ text "Show"]
             ]
        ]
```

How is the right way to send an id from the button and filter the list for the entry with this id.

Thanks for support

Answer (score 2):

Here you go
I've updated the ShowReport message to take an id (which I have assumed is a String), shown how to do the filter (up to you to decide what to do with the resulting **list**), and turned your view snippet into a function that can be mapped onto model.reports

This is only indicative as you did not provide much detail of your model

```
type Msg
    = NewReports (Result Http.Error (List Report))
      | ShowReport String
      | CloseAlert

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
case msg of
    NewReports (Ok weatherReports) ->
        ( { model | reports = weatherReports }, Cmd.none )

    NewReports (Err error) ->
        ( { model | alertMessage = Just (httpErrorToMessage error) }, Cmd.none )

    CloseAlert ->
        ( { model | alertMessage = Nothing }, Cmd.none )

    ShowReport id ->
        let report = 
            List.filter (\rep -> rep.id == id) model.reports
        in 
        (model, Cmd.none)

--VIEW

mkShowItem id =
    td []
        [
        button
        [ class "button small"
        , onClick (ShowReport id)
        ]
        [ text "Show"]
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, Simon. 
I completed the code with the missing model..
The ShowReport still throws errors "model.reports" seems not to be sufficient..

Comment: The 2nd argument to function `filter` is causing a mismatch.

78|                     List.filter (\item -> item == id) model.reports
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Function `filter` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:

    List Int

But it is:

    List Report

Comment: As I said at the time of writing the details of your model we're not available so I've now updated the answer